# jmeter getting Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: jmeter

While configuring HTTP request and putting parameters in proxy server GUI, I added the name and pass of the proxy to the HTTP authorization manager.

But I am still getting  error

> Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: If you configure the same proxy through your browser do you get the same error?

Comment: can you take a screenshot?

Comment: sreisman yes i did and didnt get any error

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) is a different beast, it won't work for proxy authentication.

You need to provide proxy credentials along with hostname and port, in order to apply the setting to all HTTP Request samplers use one of the following approaches:

1. Pass proxy host, port and credentials via [command line arguments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) like:

   ```
   jmeter -H proxy_host -P proxy_port -U username -a password ....
   ```
2. Configure proxy parameters using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/http-request-defaults) like:

   [image: HTTP Request Defaults]

Comment: Dmitri i did put all the data like in the screenshot still not working in the vm, but on my local computer its working any idea?